# Iterating like tree method in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Input :

[image]

Expected Output :

```
   LEVEL LEVEL-1 LEVEL-2 LEVEL-3 LEVEL-4  LEVEL-5   LEVEL-6  Value  Result      Explanation
0      1     A01     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN       NaN     10     550        = I3 + H2
1      2     NaN    A011     NaN     NaN      NaN       NaN     20     540        = I4 + H3
2      3     NaN     NaN   AO111     NaN      NaN       NaN     30     520        = I5 + H4
3      4     NaN     NaN     NaN  A01111      NaN       NaN     40     490   = I6 + i9 + H5
4      5     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  AO11111       NaN     50     180   = I8 + I7 + H6
5      6     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN  AO111111     60      60             = H7
6      6     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN  AO111112     70      70             = H8
7      5     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  AO11112       NaN     80     270     = I11+I10+H9
8      6     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN  AO111121     90      90            = H10
9      6     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN  AO111122    100     100            = H11
```

Explanation:
I have to get the Result column on the basis of Explanation Column. This Explanation column is made on basis Tree type. For example AO111121 & AO111122 are children's of its immediate parent AO11112 so AO11112 = AO111121 + AO111122 + AO11112 accordingly.

Comment: Can you share this file please?

Comment: Are You asking the excel file.
How can I share that

Comment: You can update your post with the output of `print(pd.read_csv('data.csv').to_string(index=False))`

Comment: I added that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
# Consolidating nodes and finding parents
df["Node"] = df["LEVEL-1"]
for level in range(2, 7):
    col, last_col = df[f"LEVEL-{level}"], df[f"LEVEL-{level - 1}"]
    df.loc[col.notna(), "Node"] = col 
    df.loc[col.notna(), "Parent"] = last_col.ffill()
df = df.drop(columns=[col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("LEVEL-")])

# Identifying childs
df = df.merge(
    df.Node.groupby(df.Parent).apply(set).rename("Childs"),
    left_on="Node", right_on="Parent", how="left"
)

# Recursively adding up results
def result(childs):
    return df.loc[df.Node.isin(childs), "Result"].sum()

df["Result"] = df.Value
for level in range(5, 0, -1):
    add_results = df.loc[df.LEVEL.eq(level), "Childs"].map(result)
    df.loc[df.LEVEL.eq(level), "Result"] += add_results
```

Result for `df`

```
   LEVEL LEVEL-1 LEVEL-2 LEVEL-3 LEVEL-4  LEVEL-5   LEVEL-6  Value  Result_exp
0      1     A01     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN       NaN     10         550
1      2     NaN    A011     NaN     NaN      NaN       NaN     20         540
2      3     NaN     NaN   AO111     NaN      NaN       NaN     30         520
3      4     NaN     NaN     NaN  A01111      NaN       NaN     40         490
4      5     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  AO11111       NaN     50         180
5      6     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN  AO111111     60          60
6      6     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN  AO111112     70          70
7      5     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  AO11112       NaN     80         270
8      6     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN  AO111121     90          90
9      6     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN  AO111122    100         100
```

is

```
   LEVEL  Value  Result_exp      Node   Parent                Childs  Result
0      1     10         550       A01      NaN                {A011}     550
1      2     20         540      A011      A01               {AO111}     540
2      3     30         520     AO111     A011              {A01111}     520
3      4     40         490    A01111    AO111    {AO11111, AO11112}     490
4      5     50         180   AO11111   A01111  {AO111111, AO111112}     180
5      6     60          60  AO111111  AO11111                   NaN      60
6      6     70          70  AO111112  AO11111                   NaN      70
7      5     80         270   AO11112   A01111  {AO111122, AO111121}     270
8      6     90          90  AO111121  AO11112                   NaN      90
9      6    100         100  AO111122  AO11112                   NaN     100
```

Be aware that in the dataframe you've provided you're using `0` and `O` inconsistently.

Comment: but Some time there will be some strings inside them

Comment: @JagadeeshkumarViswanathan Added a new version, could you try?